# Quick Ruby on Rails question on redirect_to in the same Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

Inside a given controller "BobsController" - is the controller argument on the redirect_to method optional, so that:

```
redirect_to(:controller => 'bobs', :action => 'index')
```

is the same as:

```
redirect_to :action => 'index'
```

when being used inside the BobsController class?  I assume because the controller is derived from the current controller?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you're correct.  It assumes the current controller if :controller is not provided.

Comment: Thanks so much (now to remove a  whole bunch of redundant code from my controllers).

Comment: If you're using RESTful Rails resources, you can also use the easier named routes generated by the router: map.resources :bobs would give you the ability to do redirect_to bobs_path....

Comment: how to redirect to current action only..is there a way to avoid passing same action name again